# Displaying unicode text in a graph using matplotlib and networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, utf-8, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I'm trying to display a graph containing 3 nodes. The labels of the nodes are in Devanagari. I tried using Font Properties in matplotlib for a single devanagari word and it works fine. It doesn't display the node labels when the same is used to plot a graph. Can anyone find a way to display the devanagari text in the graph? I'm using Python 2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# -- coding: utf-8 -- 
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import networkx as nx
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='NotoSerifDevanagari-Regular.ttf') 
x=0.2
y=0.2
labels={}
graph = nx.Graph()

words= ["सनरायझर्स"," जैत ","जोडलें"]


for word in words:
   w = word.decode('utf-8')
   graph.add_node(w)
   labels[w]=w
graph.add_edge(words[0].decode('utf-8'),words[1].decode('utf-8'))
graph.add_edge(words[1].decode('utf-8'),words[2].decode('utf-8'))
pos=nx.spring_layout(graph)

nx.draw(graph,labels=words, with_labels = True)
plt.text(x, y, word, fontproperties=prop) 
plt.show()enter code here
```